# Export table data into csv file using mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to export a table data into a csv file using mysqldump.

I want to make something like:

```
mysqldump --compact --no_create_info --tab=testing --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=, -uroot -proot mydatabase mytable
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
(Errcode: 13) when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'
```

I made my testing folder writable(I'm using Ubuntu as enviornment). Can somenone explain how to export a table in a CSV file, or how to modify my command shell in order to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The trouble with all these `INTO OUTFILE` or `--tab=tmpfile`  answers is that it requires running **mysqldump** *on the same server* as the MySQL server.

My solution was simply to use `mysql` (NOT `mysqldump`) with the `-B` parameter, inline the SELECT statement with `-e`, then massage the ASCII output with `sed`, and wind up with CSV including a header field row:

Example:

```
 mysql -B -u username -ppassword database -h dbhost -e "SELECT * FROM accounts;" |sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g"
```

> "id","login","password","folder","email"
>   "8","mariana","57d40c8a954bc9e65f401592062019b1457be359","mariana",""
>   "3","squaredesign","b01134fac01dab765bcb55ab0ca33f9ec2885a7b","squaredesign","mkobylecki@squaredesign.com"
>   "4","miedziak","601f1889667efaebb33b8c12572835da3f027f78","miedziak","miedziak@mail.com"
>   "5","Sarko","480225f1ac707031bae300f3f5b06dbf79ed390e","Sarko",""
>   "6","Logitrans
>   Poland","9033b6b3c4acbb27418d8b0b26f4c880ea6dea22","LogitransPoland",""
>   "7","Amos","50f5604164db2d5ff0e984f973d2202d5358b6a6","Amos",""
>   "9","Annabelle","07e832cb64e66fa03c13498a26a5f8e3bdebddf1","Annabelle",""
>   "11","Brandfathers and
>   Sons","f08b194668249e4cb81fbb92df846e90569f5c01","BrandfathersAndSons",""
>   "12","Imagine
>   Group","e86f1645504c7d5a45ed41d16ecc39ed19181773","ImagineGroup",""
>   "13","EduSquare.pl","80c3c099f4ecc043a19f1527400d63588567a0ad","EduSquare.pl",""
>   "101","tmp","b01134fac01dab765bcb55ab0ca33f9ec2885a7b","_","WOBC-14.squaredesign.atlassian.net@yoMama.com"

Add a `> outfile.csv` at the end of that one-liner, to get your CSV file.